# Higher-order function from old Python version to Python 3

Tags: python, lambda

Does anyone know how to translate this HOF from previous version of Python to Python 3?

```
apply_each = lambda fns, args=[]: map(apply, fns, [args]*len(fns))
```

This comes from the book titled: Text Processing in Python by David Mertz.
I'm not able to use the apply function in Python 3 since it has been deprecated.
I've tried using func(*args, **kwargs) instead of apply(func, args, kwargs), but I get this TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable.
I've also found those notes which show what the function is supposed to return:
https://wiki.python.org/moin/TextProcessingInPython

here's my try at the code:

```
apply_each = lambda fns, args=[]: map(fns, *args)
args = [5.4, 6.3, 6.3]
print(list(apply_each(approx, args)))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define your own `.apply`:

```
>>> def apply(f, args):
...     return f(*args)
...
>>> apply_each = lambda fns, args=[]: map(apply, fns, [args]*len(fns))
```

Or all in one go:

```
apply_each = lambda fns, args=[]: map(lambda f, args: f(*args), fns, [args]*len(fns))
```

But this is poor style, the only advantage of a lambda is that it is anonymous, if you are going to assign it to a name, that defeats the purpose. This is better style:

```
def apply(f, args):
    return f(*args)

def apply_each(fns, args=()):
    return map(apply, fns, [args]*len(fns))
```

So:

```
>>> import operator as op
>>> list(apply_each([op.add, op.sub, op.mul, op.truediv], args=[1,2]))
[3, -1, 2, 0.5]
```